# Database table optimization

Tags: sql-server, database

I have list of clients. There are approx. 2 millions record in that table. The table has the following structure:

> ID(int),FLM,email,address,phone,BDAy; each of nvarchar type except BDay.

I have two non-clustered index on ID and FLM columns. When I execute query such as

```
SELECT * FROM tbl where FLM LIKE 'value'
```

I experiencing delay in approx. 1 minute. Therefore questions:

- Will adding clustered index on FLM change performance?
- what else I can optimize here?

How am I getting result from program? Using `SqlConnection` to connect then specifying query in `SQlCommand` object and then getting data via `DataReader`. Maybe here I can optimize this to get better result( by using dataset maybe)?

Comment: What form does value take? Are you using wildcards `'%value%'`? What does "show plan" show? I suspect a table scan is occurring if you are using an initial % in your pattern.

Comment: Yes, I'm using wildcards that's why in query like, not = statement. But even if I'm not using wildcards, I have to wait that long.

Comment: As a rule of thumb, Table should have clustered index. You should create clustered index on column which have most unique rows and is incremental. Also clustered index should not be wide so avoid having clustered index on string columns.

Comment: @Ben in my plan table scan occurs and costs 99%. Does that mean full scan?

Comment: Yes it means a full scan. Because you are doing "select *" and using wildcards, SQl thinks "I'm going to have to read the whole table anyway, may as well do it first time". To make it use the index specify an index hint.

Answer (score 0):

Make ID a clustered Index rather than a non-clustered one. Considering only the query you have posted, the non-clustered index on FLM column is not going to do anything, so you can remove it.

Hope the Clustered Index will improve the performance.